# Loading a panoramic image into A-Frame

Tags: image, cors, aframe, webvr, 360-panorama

Im just beginning to learn about A-Frame and Im attempting to load a local image taken with my ricoh theta into an a-frame scene. I ran into the CORS issue and attempted to use the A-Frame asset loader which adds the cors header but was told it "can't upload" the image.

Do I need to prepare the image in some way in order to have the asset loader accept the image? How do I overcome the CORS issue?

Forgive my ignorance.  Im sure the answer to this question will help alot of people interested in A-frame.

Comment: The A-Frame asset loader does not seem to be working right now. Have you tried hosting the image on GitHub Pages as suggested in the FAQ? https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-asset-e-g-image-video-model-not-load

Comment: Are you serving the image with CORS allowed headers?

Comment: Thanks! Im working on hosting the image on github pages.  The photo is local .  Do I have to upload it to a second party in order to serve it with a CORS allowed header?

Answer (score 0):

The A-Frame Asset Uploader is broken because we have expired keys for UploadCare. You can host the image in other places such as GitHub Pages, or image hosting services such as imgur

Comment: well, just update those keys) contact help@uploadcare.com if in doubt.

Comment: It's a paid service and some coordination is involved.

Comment: Sure, let's coordinate outside of SO :)